# Regex-EBNF conversion issue python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, expression, ebnf

Am new to python and am trying my hands on regex and EBNF. Am not sure if my conversion are accurate. I just need a second look at my conversions.

```
 EBNF                                      REGEX
 a{a} (convereted from regex)              a+  

 a{{ab} ya}  (convereted from regex)       a((xa)*ya)

 e{e}{bb|p[p] [p]d}c                       e+(bb|(p)*d)?c
```

Comment: what is the exact question ?  is expression in column 1 equivalent to column 2 in their repective context ?

Comment: @NeronLeVelu..Yes..for the first two..is the ebnf equivalent to the regex and for the last one is the regex equivalent to the ebnf. An correction would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

While the features of EBNF are straightforward, the actual notation can appear in a few different forms. I'll be using the terminology and notation of [ISO/IEC 14977 : 1996(E)](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=26153) (it's available as a PDF if you Google for it).

The regular expression `a+` is a Terminal-string (§5.2) followed by a Repeated-sequence (§5.6). The EBNF form would be:

```
"a", {"a"}
```

The regular expression `a((xa)*ya)` is a bit more complicated. If you first look at just `a(ya)`, you have a Terminal-string followed by a Grouped-sequence (§5.4). It would look like this:

```
"a", ("y", "a")
```

The subexpression `(xa)*` by itself is a Repeated-sequence containing a sequence of two Terminal-strings. It alone would look like this:

```
{"x", "a"}
```

You can combine the previous two items to obtain the EBNF form for the complete expression:

```
"a", ({"x", "a"}, "y", "a")
```

The final expression introduces two additional concepts, specifically the Definitions-list (§5.10) and the Optional-sequence (§5.5). The subexpression `(bb|(p)*d)` includes a Definitions-list. The EBNF for this subexpression alone is the following:

```
("b", "b" | {"p"}, "d")
```

When you include the optional quantifier, which expands this to the subexpression `(bb|(p)*d)?`, you update the EBNF to the following:

```
[("b", "b" | {"p"}, "d")]
```

Since the Optional-sequence also serves as a grouping construct, you can remove the unnecessary start-group-symbol and end-group-symbol to obtain the following:

```
["b", "b" | {"p"}, "d"]
```

By combining the steps used above, you can obtain the EBNF form for the complete third regular expression:

```
"e", {"e"}, ["b", "b" | {"p"}, "d"], "c"
```